# Rails + state_machine: duplicated object's state attribute is `nil` after calling .reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, persistence, state-machine

My app uses the `state_machine` gem to manage states on several ActiveRecord classes. Recently I've begun working on a feature that allows an admin to duplicated a `Job`. However, I'm finding that duplicated jobs are ending up with a `state` of `nil` after being saved. This happens whether the Job is duplicated through the new admin feature or manually in the console. Here is some relevant code:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
...
state_machine :state, initial: :posted do
...
end

# job_duplicator.rb
class JobDuplicator
  def self.duplicate(job)
    new_job = job.dup
    new_job.assign_attributes(
        state: "posted",   
        discount_code_id: nil,
        credit_applied: 0
        )
    new_job
  end
end

class Admin::JobsController < AdminController
  ... 
  def duplicate
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @new_job = JobDuplicator.duplicate(@job)
    if @new_job.save
      redirect_to edit_admins_job_path(@new_job), notice: "Successfully duplicated #{@job.to_s} as #{@new_job.to_s}. You can edit the details below, if you'd like."
    else
      redirect_to :back, alert: "There was a problem duplicating #{@job.to_s}."
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Here is what happens when I do the process in the console:

```
[1] pry(main)> j = Job.first
[2] pry(main)> k = JobDuplicator.duplicate(j)
[3] pry(main)> k.state => "posted"
[4] pry(main)> k.save
[5] pry(main)> k.new_record? => false
[6] pry(main)> k.state => "posted"
[7] pry(main)> k.reload
[8] pry(main)> k.state => nil
```

As you can see above, the `state` becomes `nil` after the duplicated object is reloaded. The same thing happens when the process is done through the admin portal, hitting `Admin::Jobs#duplicate`. The job is created and the redirect takes place, but there's immediately a `nilClass` error related to the `state` on the page to which the admin is redirected. The other attributes that are assigned by `JobDuplicator` (`discount_code_id` and `credit_applied`) persist correctly.

Can someone who knows the gem better than me perhaps explain why this is happening and what I can do to get around it?